# Can I generate a .sql update script from an edmx file?

Tags: sql, edmx, ef-database-first

I know its inherently backwards in terms of how database first should work but as it stands im unable to convert the project to be code first; i was wondering if it was possible to generate a sql update script based on changes made in the edmx, opposed to a full database regeneration or updating the edmx from the database?

Comment: Does this help? https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/entity-framework-4-0-generating-sql-script-from-model

Comment: unfortunately not,  I looked at that blog when I first started looking into this and the script that it creates drops and recreates all the tables in the database as a consequence.

Comment: So create a new database and use Schema Compare between the two to generate your scripts (I'm assuming when you say "Update script" you mean update the table schema rather than updating any data)

Comment: that would work, cheers!